# how to read gml file with label in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I have a weighted network gml file and have trouble read it successfully in jupyter notebook. A part of my file is shown as follows:

```
graph
[
   node
   [
      id 1

   ]
   node
   [
      id 2

   ]

(..some nodes and edges)

 edge
   [
      source 34
      target 24
      value  4.00
   ]
   edge
   [
      source 11
      target 6
      value  3.00
   ]
]
```

my file can be downloaded via: Visit https://area51.stackexchange.com/https://gawron.sdsu.edu/python_for_ss/course_core/book_draft/Social_Networks/Networkx.html 9.2.6

The code I use to read file is:

```
import networkx as nx
kn2 = nx.read_gml('/Users/kate/Desktop/karate_club/weighted_karate.gml')
```

---

and the error:

```
NetworkXError: node #0 has no 'label' attribute
```

I except to read the file successfully with the label and weights.

Comment: For each edge i want to print the edge and its weight, code:```from collections import Counter
all_node_ctr = Counter()
for (u,v) in all_edges:
    for x in (u,v):
        all_node_ctr[x] += 1
    print('%-4s %-4s %.3f' % (u,v,kn2.edges.data('value')))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[read_gml](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gml.read_gml.html?highlight=read_gml#networkx.readwrite.gml.read_gml) automatically renames parsed nodes:

> `label (string, optional)` – If not `None`, the parsed nodes will be renamed according to node attributes indicated by `label`. Default value: `‘label’`.

You can set `label` to `'id'` so `read_gml` will be set node IDs according to `id` field in .gml file:

```
import networkx as nx
kn2 = nx.read_gml('karate.gml', label='id')
print(kn2.edges)
```

> `[(1, 32), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), ...]`

---

**Edit 1:** Looks like the book is a little outdated. For a stable version `read_gml` need a `multigraph 1` line in the .gml file if it has edge duplicates. You should add it:

> ```
> Creator "Jean Mark Gawron on Sunday, 15. December 2013 02:40PM"
> graph
> [
>    multigraph 1 <------------------ HERE
>    node
>    [
>       id 1
>    ]
>    node
>    [
>       id 2
>    ]
> ...
> ```

Then you can access values of edges like this:

`kn2.edges.data('value')`

or sort them like in the book:

```
all_edges = sorted(
    kn2.edges(),
    key=lambda x: kn2.get_edge_data(*x)[0]['value'],
    reverse=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks vurmux but after add label='id' I still can't read it and get an Hint:  If this is a multigraph, add "multigraph 1" to the header of the file. should I modify the original gml file or do something in the code?
 And in part 9.2.6 on the link, the author use weighted edges and he sorted the edges by weight as well.

Comment: It works thank you! By the way, when I trying to print its 'value' alone, there comes an TypeError: must be real number, not MultiEdgeDataView. Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: It works thank you! By the way, when I trying to print its 'value' alone, there comes an TypeError: must be real number, not MultiEdgeDataView. Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: You can access it like: `kn2.edges[your_edge]['value']`